# How to push object in array with those records in object should not reside under object name?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push data in array but I don't want that data to come under any object.

**Expected output:**

```
name : "abc"
array1 : [],
flag : false
myObj1 : {}
myObj2 : {}
```

But I am getting data in arr variable in array like below:

```
myObj :
    name : "abc"
    array1 : [],
    flag : false
myObj1 : {}
myObj2 : {}
```

**Code:**

```
var arr = [];
function pushData(myObj)
{
    arr.push(
            {
                myObj
                myObj1 : { title: myObj.name, flag: true, value: 0 },
                myObj2:  { location : null,age : 10 }
                //some other objects which I want to initialize here only
            }
        );
}
```

Is this possible to get **expected output** in **arr** variable?

Comment: could you please use valid JSON?

Comment: You're missing commas in several places, and haven't shown how `pushData` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to assign Object1 and 2 to Object:

```
arr.push(Object.assign({},myObj,{
                myObj1 : { title: myObj.name, flag: true, value: 0 },
                myObj2:  { location : null,age : 10 }
 }));
```

Will create this:

```
[{
  name : "abc"
  array1 : [],
  flag : false
  myObj1 : {title,flag,value}
  myObj2 : {location,age}
}];
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Can you explain a bit regarding your code ??

Comment: @Learning if ive got you right you want myObj1 and myObj2 to be part of myObject. Thats why ive *assigned* them to myObject...

Comment: Yeah i got that but my question is that how your property name,array1 and flag doesnt comes under myobj and how it is exactly matching with my expected output?

Comment: @Learning i believed they were part of myObj?

Comment: Yeah true but if you see my code then why does i am getting those 3 properties under myObj and not as seperated like in my expected output?Sorry if my question sounds silly

Comment: @Learning {myObj} is ES6 ( i believe you didnt know that) and is equal to {myObj:myObj} . Now clearer?

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation and help too and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're transpiling your code with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for ES6 capabilities, you can use [object spread properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/):

```js
var arr = [];

function pushData(myObj) {
  arr.push({
    ...myObj,
    myObj1: {},
    myObj2: {}
  });
}

pushData({ name: "abc", array1: [], flag: false });

console.log(arr);
```

Here's the [current compatibility stats](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-object_spread_properties).